# Nordic Skiing training program?

Tags: training, books, skiing

I have been getting into Nordic Skate skiing the last few years and have my first ski marathon coming up this winter.  I am looking for a book, website, magazine, etc that can help me prepare.  In particular I am looking for a resource to cover 1 or all of the following:

-workouts
-nutrition
-advanced technique
-overall training program

Does any one have any good suggestions of a resource I can use to guide my training?  Most books I have found so far are over 30 years old and therefore I'm not sure if they are still relevant.

Comment: Are you going to be doing Classic or Skating?

Comment: I will be Skating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off you should be doing a lot of dry land training now. i.e. running, if you have roller skies you should be using them now. For a 42-50k Ski race I would consider running at least a half-marathon running race. You should be cross training throughout the summer months.

We bought a pair V2 and OneWay roller skies here http://xcski.gearwest.com/category/skate-roller-skis/400465/393504/394270 You can also rent roller skies for the season.

This is a great resource for training ideas
http://www.nordicskiracer.com/training101.asp

More resources
http://www.skipost.com/training.htm

Here are training programs.
http://www.xczone.com/skifitnesstrg.pdf

For advanced technique I would consider taking some ski lessons. We live in the Twin Cities and there are some great coaches and teachers along with groups you can join. We have a number of groups that meet on Meetup.com.